# Programmatically-Created Custom UITableViewCell does not populate with given data - Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

This hasn't gone as expected. I'm positive that I have accessed the values correctly, so why would this not populate the two cells? I would assume it'd be something simple I just passed over, but I can't figure it out for the love of me. Thanks in advance.

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    var events: Dictionary<String, [String]> = ["0": ["Monroe Family", "La Cañada", "8:30"], "1": ["Steven Family", "Glendale", "7:30"]]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.registerClass(EventCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "EventCell")

        tableView.dataSource = self;
        tableView.delegate = self;
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return events.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cellIdendifier: String = "EventCell"

        var cell: EventCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdendifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as EventCell

        if let i = events[String(indexPath.row)] {
            cell.eventName.text = i[0]
            cell.eventCity.text = i[1]
            cell.eventTime.text = i[2]
        }

        cell.sizeToFit()

        return cell


    }
}
```

**EventCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

class EventCell: UITableViewCell {

    var eventName: UILabel = UILabel()
    var eventCity: UILabel = UILabel()
    var eventTime: UILabel = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.contentView.addSubview(eventName)
        self.contentView.addSubview(eventCity)
        self.contentView.addSubview(eventTime)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        eventName = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 10, self.bounds.size.width - 40, 25))
        eventCity = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0))
        eventTime = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0))

    }

}
```

Comment: try setting the background color of your custom labels and make sure those are at least showing up. (`eventName.backgroundColor = UIColor.magentaColor()`)

Comment: Have you checked whether cellForRowAtIndexPath  method is getting called or not? Put a breakpoint and use stepOver breakpoint functionality and debug line by line.

Comment: Your class does not conform to UITableViewDataSource

Comment: @zisoft No, I can see it.

Comment: @Bluehound Although not the answer, I'll look into that. Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with your `EventCell` class.

You are adding labels to `contentView` in the `init` and you are again allocating it in the `layoutSubviews`. So you added a label when cell is initialized and later you re-allocated it. So you lost the connection between the first label object. So when you access those labels from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` , you are getting the second label instance (that was not added to the cell) not the displaying one (first label instance)

Comment: In fact he/she sets the labels in init, adds those to the contentView and set different labels in layoutSubviews.